# Altering the margins of a legend in R

Tags: r, bar-chart, legend

I am very new to R, so I'm struggling here a bit and I haven't found an answer to my problem.

I'm trying to produce a simple bar-chart in R, and I have set my x-axis variable labels to be vertical, using `las=2`. I then changed the margins for the barplot so that the labels would not overlap the xlab label, using `par(mar=c(20,15,5,3))` and `par(mgp=c(6,1,0))`.

I would like to add a legend to this, but the one I have has adopted the margin dimensions of the graph itself, so that it appears too big and does not fit. I tried using `cex` but that only affects the text in the legend. Is there anyway for me to change the legend margins (or the graph margins) independently?

Here's what I have coded:

```
par(mar=c(20,15,5,3))
par(mgp=c(6,1,0))
par(xpd=TRUE)
barplot(
  names.arg=c("Africa", "Central America, South America, Caribbean", 
              "Middle East", "Central and Eastern Europe", 
              "South and East Asia"),
  cex.names=0.8, las=2, t(YLL), 
  ylab="Percentage (%)", ylim=c(0,100), main="", beside=TRUE, 
  col= c("green4", "orange"),xlab="Regions", mar=c(20,15,5,3)
)
legend(
  10, 100, 
  legend=c("Communicable diseases", "Communicable diseases"), 
  fill= c("green4", "orange"), cex=0.7
)
```

I will really appreciate the help, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the arguments of `legend` function: `y.intersp`, `x.intersp` and `text.width` for reduce the size of the legend.

Here an example:

```
set.seed(55) # Set the seed of R‘s random number generator
x <- 1:10
y <- runif(10, min=0, max=100) # Generating random numbers
z <- runif(10, min=0, max=100) # Generating random numbers
plot(x,y, type="l", ylim=c(0,100), ylab="y and z")
par(new=TRUE)
plot(x,z, type="l", col="red", ylim=c(0,100), ylab=NA, xaxt='n', yaxt='n')
legend("topright", c("y","z"), lty="solid", col=c("black", "red"))
```

[image: before]

And same code modifiying the `legend` function:

```
set.seed(55) # Set the seed of R‘s random number generator
x <- 1:10
y <- runif(10, min=0, max=100) # Generating random numbers
z <- runif(10, min=0, max=100) # Generating random numbers
plot(x,y, type="l", ylim=c(0,100), ylab="y and z")
par(new=TRUE)
plot(x,z, type="l", col="red", ylim=c(0,100), ylab=NA, xaxt='n', yaxt='n')
legend("topright", c("y","z"), lty="solid", col=c("black", "red"), y.intersp=0.5,x.intersp=0.5,text.width=0.1)
```

[image: after]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood your problem correctly, but maybe you can try x.intersp or y.intersp to modify the spacing in the x and y axis of your legend. For example, you could add x.intersp=0.5 to bring the elements of your legend closer in the x axis.

If this does not work and you provide a screenshot, maybe I could try to help you better.

Comment: Hi there, the problem isn't the position of the legend, but the margin (spacing) size around the legend. It's too big for the graph because I changed the margin sizes of the graph to compensate for the x axis labels overlapping the xlab label. I wanted to put an image of the graph up, but I'm not permitted to do so.

Comment: So weird... that never happened to me. By "spacing arround the legend" you mean that there is a lot of white space around the text of your legend? Maybe you can remove the background and border of the legend with bty="n", that way it won't matter if the legend has big margins.

Another thing that I can think of, is that maybe you don't need to alter the margins so much so your labels won't overlap. You can introduce breaks in your text, for example
"Central America, \n South America, \n Caribbean"
so it will be written in three lines and it won't overlap with the x label.

Comment: Thank you. I will try that now.