# How to set the size of a legend in a barplot in R?

Tags: r, bar-chart, legend

I have created a grouped bar chart using `barplot` in R. Unfortunately, the legend appears abnormally huge and even gets cut off, as you can see from the figure.

[image]

Here is the code I have used.

```
# data:
#           a         b        c
# U 0.4405316 0.6553628 0.646097
# H 0.0544850 0.0283912 0.028300
# L 0.0046512 0.0015773 0.003371
# M 0.1860465 0.1064669 0.118002
# O 0.2478405 0.1861199 0.179914
# P 0.0006645 0.0007886 0.002350
# T 0.0677741 0.0205047 0.021761

    data <- cbind(c(0.4405316, 0.0544850, 0.0046512, 0.1860465, 0.2478405, 
                    0.0006645, 0.0677741),
            c(0.6553628, 0.0283912, 0.0015773, 0.1064669, 0.1861199, 
              0.0007886, 0.0205047),
            c(0.646097, 0.028300, 0.003371, 0.118002, 0.179914, 
              0.002350, 0.021761))
    data <- data.frame(data)
    names(data) <- c("a","b","c")
    rownames(data) <- c("U","H","L","M","O","P","T")

    barplot(t(as.matrix(data)), beside=TRUE, 
            col=heat.colors(length(colnames(data))),ylim=c(0,1))
    legend("topright",cex=1,fill=heat.colors(length(colnames(data))), 
           legend=colnames(data),bty = "y")
```

Why is it so bad? The problem doesn't seem to occur [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13936223/legends-in-barplot-not-appearing-properly), where setting the option "topright" does the job.
I have tried setting the option cex lower than one, but the text of the legend becomes too small, while the problem here is the huge size of the rectangles in the legend.
Any idea?

Update: I realise now that a similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32543240/altering-the-margins-of-a-legend-in-r?rq=1) (basically unanswered).

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior... The legend appears just fine for me. Did you try to close R and start in a fresh session? (the reason being that maybe you set some of the variables in `par()` by inadvertence at some point)

Comment: I should have said that I'm using Rstudio. I cleared everything in the environment, all the plots, restarted the browser, but the plot still has the same problem.

Comment: I am using Rstudio as well... Given this, it might be worth trying to fill a bug report for the Rstudio team...

Comment: What version of RStudio are you using? What OS?

Comment: RStudio 0.98.501 on Ubuntu 15.04

Comment: I can't reproduce either. RStudio 9.9.99 (according to help->about) on Ubuntu ARM. By the way, it's easier for people to reproduce and troubleshoot if you use `dput(data)` to give us something we can cut and paste.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know `dput`, thanks! Anyway, I have edited the code to facilitate reproduction.